# How fetch json data in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

I am new in react and I'm learning on official website with tutorial help.
So, I have structure in my app:

```
-js
  -notes.js
  -comment.json
index.html
```

notes.js have next code:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
                <CommentForm />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
            return (
                <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
                    {comment.text}
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="commentForm">
                Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="comment">
                <h2 className="commentAuthor">
                    {this.props.author}
                </h2>
                <p>
                    {this.props.children}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url="comment.json" pollInterval={2000} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Here my file data "comment.json":

```
[
  {"id": "1", "author": "Pete Hunt", "text": "This is one comment"},
  {"id": "2", "author": "Jordan Walke", "text": "This is *another* comment"}
]
```

But it doesn't work and in console I have next message:

```
jquery.js:9392 GET http://helper.com/views/com.json?_=1471986105038 404 (Not Found)
```

and another one:

```
notes.js:22 com.json error Not Found
```

Maybe I write wrong url parametr in:

```
   <CommentBox url="comment.json" pollInterval={2000} />
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try `url="/comment.json"`

Comment: Unfortunately problem is the same:
`notes.js:22 /comment.json error Not Found`

Comment: @vijayst maybe you have other ideas? can you help me please?

Comment: I just checked the folder structure. It should be "js/comment.json". You should be able to manually get the json in the browser as you would normally do with any file.

Comment: @vijayst thank you! the reason was wrong path!